# PLSQL CLOB maximum length error

Tags: plsql, clob

My code/PLSQL function  is as below:

```
function build_update(p_table_name varchar2) --function to build update statement
return varchar2
    as
     t_string CLOB;                 
begin
for i in (select column_name from ALL_TAB_COLS where table_name = p_table_name)
 loop
  t_string := t_string || i.column_name||'='||' b' ||'.'||i.column_name||',';   

 end loop;
   t_string := to_clob(to_char(substr(t_string, 1, instr(t_string, ',', -1)-1)));
                return t_string;

end;
```

While creating dynamic sql update to be used in merge, it is showing error as can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.

Even if an using CLOB, it cant take more characters.
I have only 152 columns in my table, and for them I am making column_nameA=B.column_nameA.

Please help

Comment: last t_string assignment is not able to take long string, even if I have declared it as CLOB.As fas I know, it should as many as characters, it wants.All the characters come around 20000 characters.Than, what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since result might be to big to handle in a `varchar2` (size > `32512` on my system), you should type your return value as `CLOB` to avoid the error. But then you must handle `CLOB` in you code, which is fun.

```
declare   
    function build_update(p_table_name varchar2) --function to build update statement
    return clob as
       t_string CLOB;                 
    begin
        for i in (select column_name from ALL_TAB_COLS where table_name = p_table_name)
       loop
           t_string := t_string || i.column_name||'='||' b' ||'.'||i.column_name||',';   
       end loop;

       t_string := substr(t_string, 1, instr(t_string, ',', -1)-1);
       return t_string;

    exception
          when others then 
               dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
               dbms_output.put_line(length(t_string));
               return 'kaput';
    end;

begin
 dbms_output.put_line(substr(build_update('MY_TABLE'), 1, 32512));

exception
      when others then 
           dbms_output.put_line('-in-main:'||sqlerrm);
end;
/
```